After using HmacSHA256 still error message is : The specified key byte array is 0 bits which is not secure enough for any JWT HMAC-SHA algorithm
for generating the HmacSHA256 key i am using :
try {
            KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
            keyGen.init(256);
            SecretKey secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();
            encodedSecretKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secretKey.getEncoded());
            System.out.println("Generated secret key for JWT: " + encodedSecretKey);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to generate secret key for JWT", e);
        }

but still when requesting i am getting an error message saying :
message: "The specified key byte array is 0 bits which is not secure enough for any JWT HMAC-SHA algorithm.  The JWT JWA Specification (RFC 7518, Section 3.2) states that keys used with HMAC-SHA algorithms MUST have a size >= 256 bits (the key size must be greater than or equal to the hash output size).  Consider using the Jwts.SIG.HS256.key() builder (or HS384.key() or HS512.key()) to create a key guaranteed to be secure enough for your preferred HMAC-SHA algorithm.  See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7518#section-3.2 for more information.",
for accessing the key below is the function -
  private SecretKey getKey() {
        byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(encodedSecretKey);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }

for generating the token i am using this :
public String generateAccessToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        claims.put("roles", roles);
        return Jwts.builder()
                .claims()
                .add(claims)
                .subject(userDetails.getUsername())
                .issuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .expiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 30))
                .and()
                .signWith(getKey())
                .compact();
    }

can any one tell me why is this happening
